# how to define the intra-dependencies within JSON elements?

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

Let's say I have the following JSON which defines an API:

```
{"contract_name": "create_user",
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/users",
        "request_body": {
            "username": {
                "type": "email",
                "options": "None",
                "required": "true",
                "unique":"true"
            },
            "role": {
                "type": "string",
                "options": [
                    "TESTER",
                    "RA_DEVICE"
                ],
                "required": "true"
            },
            "userProfile": {
                "type": "object",
                "options": {
                    "TESTER": {
                        "firstName": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "options": "None",
                            "required": "true"
                        },
                        "lastName": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "options": "None",
                            "required": "true"
                        }
                    },
                    "RA_DEVICE": {
                        "deviceId": {
                            "type": "long",
                            "options": "None",
                            "required": "true",
                            "unique":"true"
                        }
                    }}
}
```

Now let's say I want to create API test-cases from generic python script(which can take any API definition and generate test-cases for it with some random values of 'type' of the element).

Problem: I want to define a condition between 'userProfile' and 'role' such that the 'userProfile' value should be based on the value of 'role'.
i.e. if my python script chooses "RA_DEVICE" as role then the value of
 'userProfile' should correspond to "RA_DEVICE" in its options to be a random number representing 'deviceId'.

Kindly suggest a way to define relationship between 'role' and 'userProfile' with consideration that my python script to generate test-cases is to be generic(can generate test-cases for any API having intra-element dependencies).